# MongoDB: How to fetch value for particular sub-field and its subsequent field in the array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB. I am trying to get field values for a particular sku from the array in the document. I tried query ({"items.sku":"abc"},{"items.price":1}) but it is giving prices for both skus. I would appreciate if anybody can tell me how I can get price for only sku:"abc" i.e 3.5?

```
{  "_id": 123,
     "store": "store1",
     "items": [ { sku: "abc", qty: 4, price: 3.5 },
              { sku: "def", qty: 3, price: 2.5 } ]
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try:

```
db.getCollection('abhey').find({"items.sku":"abc"},{_id: 0, 'items.price.$': 1})
```

In case you need more help, please feel free to write.

Comment: Thanks Abie . I tried your answer and it is working.

Comment: Nice! Can u please vote for my answer?

Comment: I need some more points (since am a new member) to vote. Appreciate your help, and will vote for sure next time.